# Python. How to get all element from xml file with concrete tag?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I use lxml.etree.

For example I have the xml file like this:

```
<Company>
  <Employee>
      <FirstName>Tanmay</FirstName>
      <LastName>Patil</LastName>
      <Valod>
          <Person Name="Jack"></Person>
      </Valod>
      <ContactNo>1234567890</ContactNo>
      <Email>tanmaypatil@xyz.com</Email>
      <Address>
           <City>Bangalore</City>
           <State>Karnataka</State>
           <Zip>560212</Zip>
           <Room>
               <Person Name="Bill"></Person>
               <Person Name="John"></Person>
           </Room>
      </Address>
  </Employee>
</Company>
```

As a result of search I want all 'persons'. 
Something like 'element.getAll('person')' which returns elements:

```
<Person Name="Jack"></Person>
<Person Name="Bill"></Person>
<Person Name="John"></Person>
```

Answer (score 4):

Check [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#tutorial) tutorial from the official Python site which shows exactly what you need.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('person.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for person in root.findall('Person'):
    do something
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use XPaths

https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath

It will probably be something like
`root.findall("//Person")` where `root` is an `ElementTree`, since `//` is find all children, immediate or otherwise, and `Person` is the node name.

Comment: I try, but it not returning any result.

Comment: We'll need to see an example of your code as well as the XML to know what's going wrong

Comment: O, I think i fix it. Always needed to add namespace before tag name. Like a .findall(".//{namespace}Person") or .findall(".//prefix:Person", namespaces_with_prefix)